# Getting wrong row index after clicking on button in QtableWidget cell in python

Tags: python

I have added button to every cell of Qtablewidget ,When I click on button It gives wrong row index for example if i click on 1st row(out of 10) button , I got row **index 0 not 1,** I am unable to understand the problem why this happen

```
self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()                              
self.table.setColumnCount(2)

for i in range (0,9):
   self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount())

   btnplot = QPushButton(self.table)
   btnplot.setText('Plot')
   btnplot.setFixedSize(50,30);
   btnplot.setStyleSheet("background-color:white;")

   self.lstdata = QtGui.QTableWidget()
   self.lstdata.setColumnCount(2)

   self.lstdata.insertRow(self.lstdata.rowCount())
   self.lstdata.setCellWidget(self.lstdata.rowCount()-1,1,btnplot);

   btnplot.clicked.connect(self.cellClick)                                                             

   self.table.setCellWidget(self.table.rowCount()-1,1,self.lstdata)



   def cellClick(self):

      button = self.sender()
      #print (button.text())
      index = self.table.indexAt(button.pos())
      currentRow = index.row()
      print currentRow
```

Please let me know the issue

Comment: for i in range (1,10)  it should be  for i in range (0,9)

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion but still have the same problem